# how to create pages and link them to a menu

Tags: menus, pages, admin-menu, sub-menu, add-menu-page

I am having some issues linking pages to the menus I have created. I used "appearance"-> "Customize"-> "Menu" and created custom menus from there since I cannot access my "Appearance/menu" properly.

From there, I am not sure how to create pages and link them to these menus I have created. My website has a static page only as a front page and every new page I create has a link with "index.php" and does not allow me to link to any menu.

Does anybody know how to go about this?

Website is www.batalhafunk.com

Thank you so much! Kelvin

[image]

Comment: Why can't you access your Appearance/Menus properly?

Comment: Hi Nathan, thanks for the response. I have added a screenshot of the "menu" screen above. Doesn't load r work properly for some reason and doesnt seem to have the right options either

Comment: My best guess is that your theme is ruining your site, OR you have a bad plugin. Switch to a vetted theme first. If you still see that, you have a bad plugin.